# Why download file from php only 1kb?

Tags: php, file, download

I try to force download a pdf file from php that are in server...but all the file that i download only 1kb size.It not the same with actual size do i need to declare file size before download?

```
<?php
$path = "C:\Users\omamu02\Desktop\TESTPRINT" ;
$file = "NMT PRV PHG 370 2017.pdf";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= $file"); //Tell the filename to the browser
header("Content-type: application/force-download");//Get and show report format 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
readfile($path); //Read and stream the file
get_curret_user();
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fix your `filename= $file` header. Wrap your `$file` variable with a `'` chars at least. Also, you don't need the closing tag in the end of the PHP file.

And I'm not sure about your headers, so I suggest you try the function below, it's quite common for any type of data and already contains some bugfixes and workarounds:

```
function download_file($file_path, $file_name = null, $file_type = 'application/octet-stream')
{
    if ($file_name === null)
    {
        $file_name = basename($file_path);
    }

    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
        @set_time_limit(0);

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: ' . $file_type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . str_replace('"', "'", $file_name) . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));

        readfile($file_path);
    }

    exit;
}
```

Comment: same result cannot open and the file size 1 kb actual 233kb

Comment: Oh, sounds like your path is wrong. Try `readfile($path . '\' . $file);`, you should provide the full path to the file into the `readfile` function, not only a directory.